# Visually identifying areas where older poles predominate?

Tags: cartography, visualisation, analysis

I have a dataset of 300,000 poles including a number of attributes including pole age.

What I'd like to do, ideally, is be able to distinguish areas that have more old poles.

Unfortunately I can't release the data for you to play with, but I have a few tools at my disposal to try to get information to stand out!

I have a map, below, that is simply a thematic map based on pole age. This is pretty naive, but allows exploration of what's there.

How can I visualise a fairly big point dataset like this to emphasise areas that have older poles?

[image: Poles by Age]

Comment: This is a good topic for discussion over in the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), but too subjective to generate one correct answer.

Comment: I think this would be better suited to a discussion forum like [CartoTalk](http://www.cartotalk.com/) rather than our focussed Q&A.

Comment: I think this is a good question and could be left open if Alex could edit it slightly. "How can I identify areas where older poles predominate", etc

Comment: I'm happy to edit it, would you like me to alter the title?

Answer (score 2):

try hex binning.

https://github.com/minus34/postgis-scripts/tree/master/hex-grid

here is some code for creating hex grids over Australia at varying levels put together by @Minus34. It's very useful for being able to show the large amount of point data into useful and spatially identical areas.

Comment: Thanks @ed-haverkamp, I have thought about Hex Grids. I could do hex bins and then find the mean or median age for the poles that fall in the bins. I'll give it a go.

Comment: @AlexLeith  you could also set up columns that have counts of each age by the categories you've set up already. Then you can compare which column has the highest value for each hex feature, then assign a value to another column that describes that dominant age grouping (category) of that hex...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to emphasize areas where the old people live, only display their dots. Mayne use a setup with layers for different age groups or a small multiples approach.

If you want to show a ratio, for example "this place has more old than young people", use any kind of choropleth map. Hexbinning or another kind of same shapes is one way, if you want to use a regular grid. Districts or similar administrative or local boundaries would be another option.